# Why doesn't this point of the quintic have a singular Hessian?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory

I am considering the quintic:

$$ x_1^5 +x_2^5 +x_3^5 +x_4^5 +x_5^5 - 5 x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5=0$$

and it is said ([Candelas et al.](https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~beuke106/HypergeometricFunctions/COGP.pdf)) that

> only one  singular point which we may as well take to be the point $(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)$.
>   The singularity is a node, that is a point for which $p$ and $dp$ both vanish but the **matrix of second derivatives is nonsingular**.

But I obtain that the previous statement is false, since the determinant of the Hessian is

$$ -12500 (-255 x_1^3 x_2^3 x_3^3 x_4^3 x_5^3 + 
   3 x_1^2 x_2^2 x_3^2 x_4^2 x_5^2 (x_1^5 + x_2^5 + x_3^5 + x_4^5 + x_5^5) + 
   8 x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 x_5 (x_3^5 x_4^5 + x_3^5 x_5^5 + x_4^5 x_5^5 + 
      x_2^5 (x_3^5 + x_4^5 + x_5^5) + x_1^5 (x_2^5 + x_3^5 + x_4^5 + x_5^5)) + 
   16 (x_3^5 x_4^5 x_5^5 + x_2^5 (x_4^5 x_5^5 + x_3^5 (x_4^5 + x_5^5)) + 
      x_1^5 (x_4^5 x_5^5 + x_3^5 (x_4^5 + x_5^5) + 
         x_2^5 (x_3^5 + x_4^5 + x_5^5))))$$

which vanishes at the point $(1,1,1,1,1)$.

This does not seem an erratum since it is mentioned in other 
 [places](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26276/the-link-of-a-singular-quintic-hypersurface-in-cp4). The only solution I can imagine is that we are in fact considering a parameter $\psi$ as a point of the singularity, such that

$$ x_1^5 +x_2^5 +x_3^5 +x_4^5 +x_5^5 - 5 \psi x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5=0$$

and we evaluate it at $\psi=1$, in that case, the Hessian (form deriving wrt. $\psi$ too) is non-singular.

Comment: I punched this into a CAS and I can confirm that the determinant of the Hessian vanishes at every singularity of that hypersurface. If you vary the constant $5$ by some small amount, the projective hypersurface becomes nonsingular. This doesn't help you understand the quote from that paper, but what you say is correct. I have no idea what they mean.

Comment: The matrix of second derivatives should be computed in local AFFINE coordinates (in particular, it is a $4\times 4$ matrix).

Comment: @Sasha Could you elaborate a bit the procedure or give a reference? I have never worked with affine spaces. In the paper they do define a symplectic basis where you have four coordinates only, but I guess it's something different.

Comment: Consider the affine chart $x_5 = 1$. Then $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ are affine coordinates. In this chart the equation looks $x_1^5 + x_2^5 + x_3^5 + x_4^5 + 1 - 5x_1x_2x_3x_4 = 0$. Its Hessian (at point $(1,1,1,1)$) is nondegenerate.